# Hide Default Custom List from Add an App

Tags: custom-list

I need to hide the Default Custom List and Documents Library from a site collection so that Users with Design Permissions are force to use custom list templates that includes mandatory columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two articles that looked useful.

This first article did work with some caveats. While I was able to hide the Custom List and Document Library options from the catalogue, I could still search for it in the search bar, and if I sort the list differently, the apps would appear again.

https://spmatt.wordpress.com/2014/05/21/hiding-the-out-of-the-box-document-library-in-sharepoint-2013/

While this one did not work in my environment, it might be of use to someone else:

http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/09/hide-sharepoint-sitelist-templates.html

I concluded that while it might be possible to hide them with some custom code on the aspx file, I'm not a programmer so this option wasn't the best for me.

While researching other matters, I stumbled upon this excellent webinar on Content Type.
http:// en.share-gate.com/blog/recording-sharepoint-webinar-understand-content-types

I had already implemented a Content Hub to have a centrally managed content type repository. What I ended up doing is modify the default OOTB Document Content Type on my content hub to include the appropriate site columns. Then published the modified content type. While this is not the original expected  result, like this solution better because if I have to modify the templates, I can easily do so now because they are Content types. My original plan with Lists Templates would have been hard to manage as more sites collections gets created.